# Updating multiple values within the one column

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have the following SQL which I have written to update a tables values:

```
Update Table
SET S_Type = 'Versus'
Where S_Type = 'REGULAR'
SET S_Type = 'Free'
Where S_Type = 'CASH';
```

My SQL is rather rusty, and my colleague told me something was up with it but didn't tell me what!

The only thing that comes to mind is I have not referred to the Table.Column in the set and Where code.

Is there any issue updating a column as such? What is the best practice when updating a column for multiple values?

Cheers

Comment: Your colleague is right. You can't use `Set` twice in the same `Update`. Either follow podiluska's answer, or write out two `Update`s, one for each value you want to replace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here , we  are using case statement and find result like as where clause :

```
update tablename
set S_Type = (case S_Type  when 'REGULAR' then 'Versus'
                           when 'CASH' then 'free' 
                           else s_type 
                           end)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Update YourTable
set S_Type = 
    case S_Type 
        when 'REGULAR' then 'Versus'
        when 'CASH' then 'free' 
        else s_type 
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SQL Server?  If you are using 2012 you can now write simplified conditional update statements using the new CHOOSE or IIF features e.g:

```
Update YourTable
set S_Type = IIF(S_Type = 'REGULAR', 'Versus', 'free')
```

My two pennies worth.